# fetch the rendered query from one Dag to another Dag

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

we have two dags in airflow, dag A having some parameterized SQL query which are getting executed in BQ using BigQuery operator. i want to write dag B which can fetch the rendered query of dag A.
any guidance ?

Comment: Could you please post your code, what you have tried and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the query can be parametrised suggest that it's a one of templated fields. Those are always rendered when a task is executed and their values are saved in `rendered_task_instance_fields` table (here is [SQLAlchemy model](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a71332ebc6375ba9907c84103a7e8f774ba9001a/airflow/models/renderedtifields.py#L36)).

So you can query this table in DAG B to get last value of task in DAG A.